# iPad, how to implement a page control view like 'SpringBoard'?

Tags: ios, ipad

as topic, I try to build the effect, but face a problem,

I use UIScrollView and PageController, it works on landscape, but not Portrait, 
if the app starting 'Portrait' mode and then when I rotate the device, the view do not fit to screen, I think that the UIScrollView content size need to redefined, then I assign the 'height' to 'width' of the content , and 'width' to 'height' of the content, but it does not properly ,

maybe we can find some exist open source code for this feature? I believe this feature 'SpringBoard' effect is very commonly.

Comment: I have fixed this problem, I redefined the content size when rotate event did... maybe have more good solution, please let me know , :-)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in the `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` for the View?  You need to make sure this returns YES for all orientations you want to support.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: it set...  the problem is confuse, if the device init Orientation is landscape then it no problem: whatever I rotate the device, the scrollview contained page view will show suit size, but if the init Orientation is Portrait, then when I rotate device to landscape, the scrollview content size seem is not right, I do not why, so I guess that I need redefined the content size....

Comment: Check out this thread.  I had a similar problem on the iPad.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686977/how-can-i-set-the-inital-orientation-for-a-uisplitviewcontroller-based-ipad-app

Answer (score -1):

try `three20` iPhone Library in Launcher feature.
Launcher have rich feature like SpringBoard